# Why doesn't off-topic section of question closure let you choose different site than meta.gis.stackexchange.com?

Tags: support, status-completed, migration

I was trying to close this question about Postgresql:  [Getting locked out of Postgresql databases](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68763/getting-locked-out-of-postgresql-databases).  The question didn't have any GIS content, so I thought it should be migrated to the [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) site.  One person had posted an answer recommending the OP come back at some point and do this, but I thought it would save time.

Upon choosing close, and choosing the Off-Topic option, this is what is shown to me.
[image: Off-Topic closure options]

It seemed that the 4th option, "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network", would be appropriate.  Upon choosing that option, here is what I see:
[image: Off-Topic Migration option]

The only option for a different site to migrate to is the [meta.gis.stackexchange.com](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com) site.  The "Vote to close" button is grayed out unless you choose this option.

If the suggestion is that the question belongs on another Stack Exchange network site, then why is the Meta site for GISse, the only available option?

I suppose it could be a means of control so that the moderators are the only people who actually migrate questions, but I thought it was worth asking, for clarity if nothing else.  It seems to offer something that you are then not allowed to do.  I do understand this question may not be appropriate for the Meta.GISse site, but it seemed the best starting place.

Comment: I want to bump this question up the list, because like @GetSpatial I'm a little frustrated that it only offers meta.gis.stackexchange.com. More and more questions are appearing where they would be more suited for OpenData SE and I don't understand why this has not been added to the list of alternate SE sites as it is so relevant and regularly keeps occurring.

Answer (score 3):

I believe SE maintains fairly stringent control over migration because each such act affects multiple sites (except the migration to the associated meta pages).  Therefore it requires a moderator to perform the migration. (Even your moderators' abilities to migrate are somewhat limited: we often consult with moderators on the target sites before migrating and migration of older questions is altogether prevented by the system.)

You can use the "Other" option to suggest a destination site: your comment will be presented to a moderator at the time they vote to close or migrate.  Your suggestions in this regard are always helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think the whole procedure for migration of questions from and to other Stack Exchange sites needs a review.  My suggestion for how to do it is in an [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90118/how-does-question-migration-work-procedurally/186461#186461) to [How does question migration work, procedurally?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90118/215590) but I think @GetSpatial's question highlights why it seems anything but streamlined at the moment.