# What ever happened to the migration to DBA.SE option?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, user-interface, migration

Some of these questions are *clearly* a much better fit for [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) why did we lose that migration option? I could have sworn it used to be there?

[Get dynamically value of a column using plpgsql](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259181/get-dynamically-value-of-a-column-using-plpgsql)

Comment: The DBA.SE [help page](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is a little bit tricky, some database questions are recommended to be asked in StackOverflow. We could not expect GIS SE users to know this and correctly flag questions from here to there, this is why I guess the answers from our moderators discourage this type of automatic migration.

Comment: As an example, when I looked at recent migrations the last one from here to DBA was rejected by that site.

Answer (score 4):

The Close option of *Migrate* is found under:

> Close > Off Topic Because... > This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

[image]

The Migrate close option requires 3000 reputation, and you do not get the option to specify your own Migrate destination - you can only select from set options, the only one on GIS.SE appears to be Meta GIS.SE.

The option above it would be a good alternative to using the Migrate option if it is not available to you.

> Questions relating to general IT or with no clear GIS component, are off-topic here but can be researched/asked at Stack Overflow (software development), Super User (computing hardware and software), Database Administrators (relational databases) and other SE sites

*Personally* I am not a fan of forced migration - I prefer to have a question closed with Off-Topic and let the asker choose to ask on the other site.

Please also see the excellent Meta SE Q&A [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work), and Meta GIS SE Q&As [Why doesn't the off-topic section of question closure let you choose a different site than meta.gis.stackexchange.com?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3275/why-doesnt-the-off-topic-section-of-question-closure-let-you-choose-a-different) and [Refinement of migration flag](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4620/refinement-of-migration-flag)

Comment: But that didn't migrate it. =(

Comment: @EvanCarroll Correct, the second option *doesn't* migrate it, but it does close it indicating to the asker that the Question is off-topic and should be asked elsewhere

Comment: "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" used to have the option to migrate inside the next dialog prompt. Then the question would actually get moved, posted there, and we'd get a redirect. My question is why is that option not there anymore.

Comment: @EvanCarroll The *only* option under that is Meta GIS SE.  This is the only option I have ever seen for GIS SE (it is different on other SE sites).  I will raise this with other moderators about whether we should have more Migrate options available.

Comment: Very cool, I hope they add it. =) It would make it a lot easier on people asking misdirected questions.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Migration should be used sparingly - I am cautious of making it *easier* to migrate instead of closing as Off-Topic and referring the asker to the other sites for them to ask there

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain whether GIS SE ever had more migration paths offered when closing as "belongs on another site" but I do have a vague recollection that there may have been perhaps 3-4 years ago.

My understanding from [@Shog9's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77264/off-topic-questions-and-redirect-to-affiliated-sites) to [When should we consider adding a default migration path?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261196) is that it is very unlikely that we would be successful in any request to have DBA SE added to the list for our migrations, and that it is usually best to close such questions here and ask their posters to ask them at DBA SE instead.

It took me a while to find the above and during the looking I came across two other Q&As that may be worth reviewing as background to why migration is generally out of favour for the SE network:

- [When voting to migrate an off-topic question, why is the list of sites limited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79960/when-voting-to-migrate-an-off-topic-question-why-is-the-list-of-sites-limited)
- [Off topic questions and redirect to affiliated sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77264/off-topic-questions-and-redirect-to-affiliated-sites)

My personal view on migration is that I usually avoid it because procedurally it has severe shortcomings, but if a ["push-pull" (and vice versa) model of migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186461/215590) were ever considered then that is something that I would be very keen to see implemented.